# SQLite & Login Beginner

Tags: php, database, sqlite, authentication

Ok so I'm diving in with not much knowledge or SQLite, I have a generic checklogin php file that I would like to connect to the db to check the login. So without much of an understanding of SQLite, what am I missing, I've never worked with database either. I just need to understand a basic starting point or concept of connecting the database to this. I have a index.html that grabs the username and pw and inputs it in to check the login with the database but having trouble connecting to database with sqlite. Every time I try to login it'll just show me this php file code, is it because it's not connected to the database?

```
<?php


$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="Test"; // Mysql username 
$password="test"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select databse.
 mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 // username and password sent from form 
 $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
 $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

 // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
 $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
 $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
 $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($myusername);
 $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mypassword);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
 $result=mysqli_query($sql);

 // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

 // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
 if($count==1){

 // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
 session_register("myusername");
 session_register("mypassword"); 
 header("location:login_success.php");
 }
 else {
 echo "Wrong Username or Password";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: what error you are getting? Are you getting the complete php code in the output? if yes then you have to run this program on webserver like apache tomcat or any other server and with a working database

Comment: Yea I'm getting the complete php code, I do have XAMPP so i'll try to run it on there. thanks!

Comment: Running it in XAMPP gave me this:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/checklogin.php on line 11
cannot connect


Line 11 is: " mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); "

So from what I'm guessing it's not connecting to the db. Where is my test.db file suppose to be at?

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps you

```
function getConnected($host,$user,$pass,$db) 
{
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if($mysqli->connect_error) 
 die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

return $mysqli;
}

$mysqli = getConnected('localhost','user','password','database');
```

if your code really not connecting to database then it will print the message 'cannot connect to db' as you have written the die() statement.

Comment: is there a specific place my database file suppose to be at and how can I be sure I set up my database file correctly?